# What does this icon in the dependency hierarchy mean and how to import the packages properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, manifest

I'm currently working with bundles in Eclipse and I found some packages aren't properly imported. I then press the "Show the plug-in dependency hierarchy" in MANIFEST.MF and found that the bundle wouldn't import the packages with this purple icon [image]. Can anyone tell me what I can do so it would read the packages as well?

Comment: I think that is the icon for a 'fragment'. You use the parent of the fragment as the dependency.

Comment: Yes, as greg-449 already said, that's a fragment. See [here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_def_plugins.htm) and [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html).